# Unwanted White space (poss padding) for wordpress site on Internet explorer 6

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, header, padding

I have unwanted White space about the header image but this only visable from IE 7 back, IE 8 and other browsers display it perfectly.

If anyone could point me in the right direction of how to correct this then that would be fab.

Thanks in advance

tim

Comment: If you could post a link, or at least the css and html code...

Comment: sure,is it the style.css file you'll need?

Comment: The css + html that belongs to the header, but a link to the blog would be more help full

Answer (score 1):

IE uses a non-standard box model and accommodations can be made in html to handle IE based weirdness. Mostly this works because it is an HTML comment statement and thus is ignored by browsers other than IE, but IE catches it and knows to run the code. This works for IE versions less than 10.

I did this years ago, and a quick web search brought me some examples at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html.

Basically you insert code such as

```
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    Special instructions for IE 6 here
    <![endif]-->
```

In the header this might be

```
    <!--[if IE 6]>
        <style type="text/css">
            img {margin-top: -10px;}
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

or to simply link in a css file only for IE 6 or earlier

```
    <!--[if lt IE 6]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="url to stylesheet for IE">
    <![endif]-->
```

In WordPress you can sneak this in using the editor in your admin pages. I use the Google Chrome browser and find the ID of the object I need to change with right-click / Inspect Element, then add appropriate code to make adjustments.